# AO Pixelated texture baking

Tags: texture-baking

What are your suggestions? I'm getting AO pixelated in the texture.
I imported this model with sketchup, but I don't think it's a problem with the faces. Is it any setting that I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Increase the amount of samples

Comment: Or bake AO in Blender Internal and increase quality of the world AO sampling

Comment: You should use 16 or more samples when baking AO.